# Print list values in same order after being converted into a set

Tags: python

For example:

```
>>> a
[2, -4, -2, 4, -3, -1, 3, 4, 2, 2]

>>> unique(a)
[2, 3, 4, -2, -4, -3, -1]
```

It gives me a list of values such that each value appears only once, but I'd like it to also print them in the same order as the original list.

Comment: your example does not preserve the order

Comment: Checkout itertools [`unique_everseen` recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Comment: Those [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) are so useful. I can't count how many times I've used that powerset recipe.

Answer (score 6):

A `set` does not have an order, so after converting a list to a set, the resulting order when iterating the elements is implementation detail.

You could use the [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to get some set behavior with an order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> a = [2, -4, -2, 4, -3, -1, 3, 4, 2, 2]
>>> x = OrderedDict.fromkeys(a)
>>> list(x)
[2, -4, -2, 4, -3, -1, 3]
```

Comment: `x.keys()` will already return a list so there is no need to explicitly pass it to the `list` function.

Comment: @ShashankGupta Python 3 will return a `KeysView` object, which is a special type iterator/generator.

Comment: Oh okay sorry, I am in Python 2 so I didn't know.

Comment: `list(x)` will also produce a list of the keys, but avoids creating the list view object (or intermediary list of keys in Python 2).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a faster (*albeit less compact*) approach, which basically iterates over the elements in the original list, checking if they are yet in a `set` you are adding to. There may be some subtle changes which could further speed up my approach:

```
def _order(orig):
    ordset = set()
    for x in orig:
        if x in ordset:
            continue
        ordset.add(x)
        yield x
def unique(orig):
    return list(_order(orig))
```

**Outputs:**

```
>>> unique(a)
[2, -4, -2, 4, -3, -1, 3]
```

---

**Benchmarking**:

[Poke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19306245/4686625):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = '''
a = [2, -4, -2, 4, -3, -1, 3, 4, 2, 2]
from collections import OrderedDict
def unique():
    x = OrderedDict.fromkeys(a)
    return list(x)
'''
>>> print (min(timeit.Timer('unique()', setup=setup).repeat(100, 1000)))
0.031305141204512665
```

The above answer:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = '''
a = [2, -4, -2, 4, -3, -1, 3, 4, 2, 2]
def _order(orig):
    ordset = set()
    for x in orig:
        if x in ordset:
            continue
        ordset.add(x)
        yield x
def unique(orig):
    return list(_order(orig))
'''
>>> print (min(timeit.Timer('unique(a)', setup=setup).repeat(100, 1000)))
0.0031761333803501657
```

This approach is nearly 10 times faster. For a small list like this, the difference is negligible, and Poke's answer is great. If you do happen to be doing this for massive lists (*e.g. 10000 times longer for instance*) however, the difference is 75 seconds compared to 5 seconds.